# adding icon to uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can I add an icon to the uisearch bar like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ya you can add the icon if you are talking about the image on left then just add a image and if you are talking about the image to the right. which i think is a search button then you can add a button and do your search code on it.

ok so what you have to do now is, i am assuming that you want to implement the search bar with icon on the toolbar. just add a UIButton and in the IB select the UIButton and go to attribute inspector and set the type to custom.

Now when you add the image to it(set the background property to the image you have selected)

By doing this you can easily resize your image.(means just resize the button, it will automatically resize your image too).

hope this will work.

Comment: I want to resize the text field and the image .But if I added the image it override the the txt field

Comment: you are talking about which image?? the left one or the right one in your provided above image.

Comment: left one . I hope you can help me